# Convert PS1 saves on PC to PS3/PSP save format

Tags: ps3, ps1

I've been hunting for some PS1 game saves as my PS1 memory cards died. GameFAQs has many more saves listed for the [Original PS1 save format rather than the PSV format](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/saves). The PS3/PSP require PSV format to work, and I don't even know what to do with the gme files GameFAQs lists for PS1.

I know I can use the Sony Memory Card adapter for physical memory cards (and I own one) but that doesn't help me here unless I can somehow copy .gme files with the adapter from my PC, then to the PS3. If I can do that, that solves the problem as well, but I don't know how/if I can do that.

How can I convert these PS1 saves (.gme) to PS3/PSP format (.psv)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This guide](http://www.ps3hax.net/showthread.php?t=28833) explains how to convert .MCR PSX memcard images to PS3 format.

[PSXGE](http://moberg-dybdal.dk/psxge/) can handle conversion between most popular PSX memcard image formats, including .GME to .MCR (the format you're looking for in PSXGE is .MC, just rename it to .MCR).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this guide:

1. Download ps1 save data
2. Put PSP in computer
3. Add new folder called ps3
4. Put ps1 save data in ps3 folder
5. Enjoy

Or

1. Download PS1 save data
2. Put PSP in ps3
3. Copy file to ps3
4. Copy ps1 save data to PSP
5. Enjoy